# Selecting a row a clicked button itemrenderer resides within?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, itemrenderer

Inside a datagrid, I essentially want to create a "download button" itemrenderer to the right of the name of a downloadable object, resulting in something like the following link:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXUlB.png

The download function operates upon the currently selected row and is called when one of the download buttons is clicked.  Therefore, I am wondering if anybody knows of a way to select the row the itemrenderer button is contained within as the active row when one of the download buttons is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this

```
var index:int = dg.itemRendererToIndex(ir);
dg.selectedIndex = index;
```

where dg is your DataGrid and ir is your itemRenderer

hope this helps.

f